# Fatal Error: call to member function addMultiOptions() on a non object in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, fatal-error, zend-form-element

I have a form element companyState which is a drop down box

```
$companyState = $this->createElement('select', 'companyState')
        ->addMultiOptions(
            array (
                '' => 'Select',

            )
        )
        ->setAttrib('id', 'companyState')          
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttribs(
            array(
                'title' => 'companyState',
                'class' => 'st-select'
            )
        )
        ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
        ->removeDecorator('label');
```

and passing the form element as $this->addElements(array($companyState));

in the controller, I am fetching the companyState names from a table and assigning to the form as below

```
$stateListObject = ST_State_StateList::readStateListWithDetailsFromDatabase();
    $stateListIterObject = new ST_State_StateListIter($stateListObject);

    $stateNameArray = array();

    for (; $stateListIterObject->valid(); $stateListIterObject->next()) {
        $stateListObject = $stateListIterObject->current();
        $stateNameArray[$stateListObject->id] = $stateListObject->state_name;
    } 

    $companySettingsFormObject = App::getForm('Company', 'ST_CompanySettingsForm');     
    $obj = $companySettingsFormObject;
    if (!($obj instanceof $companySettingsFormObject)) {
        $companySettingsFormObject = App::getForm('Company', 'ST_CompanySettingsForm');
    }

    $companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState')->addMultiOptions($stateNameArray);
```

I'm getting a Fatal Error: call to member function addMultiOptions() on a non object in zend Ocassionaly but not everytime. If I do any modification in the file like add/remove the form elements or remove the from from cache. This error occurs. Please help how to trace the problem and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try `die(var_dump($companySettingsFormObject))` to see if `$companySettingsFormObject` exists before you do something with it.

Most likely $companySettingsFormObject isn't properly created for some reason on this line:

```
$companySettingsFormObject = App::getForm('Company', 'ST_CompanySettingsForm');
```

**Edit:**

Or, the `$companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState')` is not an object. Try debugging getElement() method to see why isn't it returning an object.

You also can change

```
$companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState')->addMultiOptions($stateNameArray);
```

to

```
if (isset($companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState')) && is_object($companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState'))) {
    $companySettingsFormObject->getElement('companyState')->addMultiOptions($stateNameArray);
}
```

It will check weather the element exists and weather it is an object.

Comment: Its says its an object.How do i overcome this problem if it doesnt create an object for this form element.